# Oracle SQL - Inner Join & Count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following Oracle database, and I need to return the following:
d.directdomain, d.domaindisplayname, r.lastdate (The latest), and count(how many times, r.directdomain = d.directdomain)

basically, I have lots of "people" in **r** db, and "domains" in the **d**. I need to return how many times a person in R visited each "domain", and also return the last time they visited the domain.
I tried a few things, but it seems by using count, i need to GROUP BY the date, so that's confusing me.

Example return:
1, Site1, 21/05/13, 5
2, Site2, 20/05/13, 2

```
d
directdomain (PK)
domaindisplayname

r
rsld         (PK)
lastdate
directdomain (FK)
```

Comment: Surely you're not here to pay someone to do your work for you. How far have you gotten and what do you need help with?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT d.directdomain, 
       d.domaindisplayname,
       MAX(r.lastdate) lastdate,
       COUNT(*) rcount
  FROM d JOIN r
    ON d.directdomain = r.directdomain
 GROUP BY d.directdomain, d.domaindisplayname
```

Sample output:

```
| DIRECTDOMAIN | DOMAINDISPLAYNAME |                      LASTDATE | RCOUNT |
|--------------|-------------------|-------------------------------|--------|
|            1 |             Site1 | August, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      4 |
|            2 |             Site2 | August, 18 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd04b/1)** demo